# mysql で deadlock が発生した場合、暗黙的なコミットが発生しているように見えますが、認識は正しいですか?

Tags: mysql

**追記**

調査の結果、掲題の認識は誤っており、暗黙的なコミットは発生しておりませんでした。
そのため、本稿は、有意義な質問ではありません。
但し、ありがたいことに回答を頂いているため、削除は行わず、コミュニティによる削除を待たせていただければと思います。

---

2つのセッション(セッションA と セッションB)で deadlock が発生し、セッションBが rollback されたときに、セッションA では、暗黙的なコミットが発生しているように見えます。

この認識が正しいか、確証が持てないのですが、どこかに仕様の記載があるか、ご存知の方はいらっしゃいませんでしょうか?

[MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 14.2.10 デッドロックの検出とロールバック](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/innodb-deadlock-detection.html) によれば、

> InnoDB では、自動的にトランザクションのデッドロックが検出され、デッドロックを解除するためにトランザクション (複数の場合あり) がロールバックされます。

とあります。

また、 [MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 13.3.3 暗黙的なコミットを発生させるステートメント](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/implicit-commit.html) では、`トランザクション制御およびロックステートメント` により、暗黙的なコミットが発生する、と記載がありました。

セッションBはロールバックされ、セッションAは、トランザクション制御によりコミットされているのでしょうか?

アプリケーションコードとしては、明示的に Commit していないのに、デッドロックを起因として Commit されるとしたら、意外と気づかないのではないか、と考え、仕様を確認したく、質問しました。

Comment: user3758624 さん、もしよければ[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)して頂けませんでしょうか？　「○○と誤解していた。」というのも立派な回答として成り立ちますし、今後他の方が同じ誤解をするのを防ぐ役割を果たせます。是非よろしくお願いいたします <(_ _)>

Comment: user3758624 さん、もう一つお願いで、タイトルが削除待ちで始まると、stackoverflowの機能で、削除待ちなのか？とびっくりしてしまうので、タイトルを「mysqlで削除待ちの〜」と改題していただけませんでしょうか？

Comment: 1. 自己回答についてのヘルプを拝見したのですが、「自分の質問に対して回答する」というチェックボックスが見当たりませんでした。
2. 既に、有益な回答を頂いているため、「自己回答」とは趣が異なるのではないか、という認識です。本稿と同様の疑問を持たれた方は、ご回答をご確認いただくと良いと考えます。そのため「解決済み」にチェックをさせていただきました (その仕組みを失念しておりました

Comment: @user3758624 ヘルプに載っている「チェックボックス」の説明は**新規質問**の投稿時にしか表示されませんので、それ以外の場合は単純に質問者本人が回答を投稿すれば [自己回答] となります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

トランザクションは、その作成者が明示的に完了を示さない限り、DBにコミットされることはないと思います。そして、明示的な完了を暗に MySQL に対して示すことになる SQL 文の一覧が、 [MySQL :: MySQL 5.6 リファレンスマニュアル :: 13.3.3 暗黙的なコミットを発生させるステートメント](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/implicit-commit.html) のドキュメントで示されているのだと思います。

これは、もし、この「暗黙的なコミットを発生させるステートメント」を実行していたならば、それは他のセッションが自分のセッションとデッドロックを起こしていようがいまいが、関係なく、そのステートメントの完了でもって、暗黙のコミットが行われるのだと思います。